# Creating the new table based on Excel file dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I am not getting how to dynamically create the table in SQL server based on Excel source.

Example: i have file with month column,

This month:

```
Name Jan Feb Mar Apr
ku    1   2   2   2

Next Month:

Name Jan Feb Mar Apr may
ku    1   2   6   1   3
```

Like that my excel data will keep changing the header dynamically , so based on the excel source i have to create the table in my sql server.

If you don't mind can you please guide me how to do ?

I known openrowset function , but i need another approach method

Pls help me to understand the my issue in SQL or in SSIS or Script level to create dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Import Data Wizard from SQL Server, save the SSIS package and re-run it whenever you need it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hi Oscar, thanks for your suggestion,  Similar like i have 20 file with same header , but dynamically change the header name in month basic,so what is the best approach to do ?

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, it seems that you need to create a custom SSIS package.

Comment: Hi Oscar, Sorry for the delay response, can you please let me know what is custom SSIS package , if possible can you pls give me some idea to create the package ?

Comment: It's not a matter I can explain in a couple of comments..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx